# what is the different between using sp_xml_preparedocument and selecting from xml parameter direcly

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a Stored procedure in MSSQL 2012.

The sp get an xml datatype and insert the data into table

I found that i can use two options.

option 1

```
DECLARE @strXML AS xml  
SET @strXML = '<DocumentElement><LocationData><SL_ID>2</SL_ID>
<IsDefault>1</IsDefault></LocationData><LocationData><SL_ID>3</SL_ID>
<IsDefault>0</IsDefault></LocationData></DocumentElement>'



SELECT 
    'SL_ID' = x.v.value('SL_ID[1]','int'),
    'IsDefault' = x.v.value('IsDefault[1]','int')
 FROM @strXML.nodes('DocumentElement/LocationData') x(v)
```

option 2

```
DECLARE @strXML AS xml  
SET @strXML = '<DocumentElement><LocationData><SL_ID>2</SL_ID>
<IsDefault>1</IsDefault></LocationData><LocationData><SL_ID>3</SL_ID>
<IsDefault>0</IsDefault></LocationData></DocumentElement>'



DECLARE @hDoc int


EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @strXML

SELECT SL_ID,IsDefault
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'DocumentElement/LocationData')
WITH 
(
   SL_ID int 'SL_ID',
   IsDefault int 'IsDefault'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

what is the different between them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is the difference?

Very easy: The one is good, the other is bad

`FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

SQL-Server does not store the XML as the string you see, but as a hierarchy tree structure. The XML you see is constructed for you when you read it. All modifications, all searching / filtering with `XPath` and `XQuery` is done against a *table-like* tree. This is astonishingly fast, because there's no string parsing necessary (this is done only once, when the XML is pushed into the **native XML type**).

The old fashioned approach with `FROM OPENXML` will do this expensive process over and over...

And **very important**: The modern approach is fully *ad-hoc* (*inlined*), while the old approach needs to work procedural (cannot be used within a `VIEW` or within an *inline TVF*)

### Some background:

Read this link about [sp_xml_preparedocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-xml-preparedocument-transact-sql):

> [ xmltext ] Is the original XML document. The MSXML parser parses this
>   XML document. xmltext is a text parameter: char, nchar, varchar,
>   nvarchar, text, ntext or xml.

The parameter you pass in is handled as a string. If you pass in a **real XML** it needs to reconstruct a *string representation* of your internal XML-tree just to do the expensive parsing process again. Might be, that the process is smart enough to recognise, that the paramter is an `XML` already and can handle this more performant, but I doubt this...

Comment: what is the 1 in 'SL_ID' = x.v.value('SL_ID[1]','int')?

Comment: @eyalb. There are many `<LocationData>`. You've found already, that you can get a *derived table* using `.nodes()`. Within each `<LocationData>` there is only one `<SL_ID>`. You know this, but the engine does not know this... There might be more of them... `.value()` needs a *singleton* value. The engine must be absolutely sure to read the correct node. Therefore you place the node's position as *predicate*. Now the engine knows to read the *first* occurance of `<SL_ID>`.