# Navigate multiple nodes Xquery xml SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

Hi i have the current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tcpos-export>
  <transactions>
    <transaction>
        <code>1</code>
        <description>MAXI MERCADO SELECTO</description>
      </shop>

        <code>2</code>
        <description>MAÑANITA PANADERIA</description>
      </till>
      <cashier>
        <code>2004</code>
        <description>NELSON PANADERIA</description>
        <first-name>NELSON PANADERIA</first-name>
      </cashier>

      <trans-item type="article">
        <hash-code>832129</hash-code>
        <code>30237</code>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <unit-price>0.50</unit-price>
        <total-price>0.50</total-price>
     
      </trans-item>
      <payment type="cash">
        <code>01</code>
        <description>Efectivo</description>
        <description-translations />
        <amount>0.50</amount>
        <prepayment>false</prepayment>
        <signature-required>false</signature-required>
        <payment-timestamp>18.08.2021 06:51:27</payment-timestamp>
        <cash-change>4.50</cash-change>
        <cash-given>5.00</cash-given>
      </payment>
```

with this xquery sql 2019:

```
--procesar articulos del dia de venta
SELECT 
        trans.value('(shop/description/text())[1]','varchar(100)') tienda,
        trans.value('(till/code/text())[1]','varchar(100)') caja,
        trans.value('(cashier/code/text())[1]','varchar(100)') cajero,
        trans.value('(beginning-timestamp/text())[1]','varchar(100)') fecha,
        trans.value('(trans-num/text())[1]','varchar(100)') transaccion,
        item.value('(code/text())[1]','varchar(100)') itemcode,
        item.value('(description/text())[1]','varchar(100)') description,
     
        item.value('(hash-code/text())[1]','int') hashcode

FROM [dbo].[XmlImport] xi

CROSS APPLY xi.[LoadedXML].nodes('tcpos-export/transactions/transaction') x1(trans)

CROSS APPLY x1.trans.nodes('trans-item[
    hash-code/text() and
    not( unit-price[contains(text()[1], "-")] ) and
    not( taxable-amount[contains(text()[1], "-")] ) and
    not( delete-operator-id/text() )
]') x2(item)

CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    item.value('(quantity/text())[1]','numeric(10,3)'),
    item.value('(weight/text())[1]','numeric(10,3)'),
    item.value('(vat-code/text())[1]','varchar(100)')
) ) v(quantity, weight, vatcode)

ORDER BY hashcode;
```

im already getting those columns correctly from transactions node example cashier, till. In adition im getting info from  node. But, im confused in how i can get info from the next node

```
<payment type="cash">
        <code>01</code>
        <description>Efectivo</description>
        <description-translations />
```

i would like to get code and description

i tried the following:

adding this as additional cross apply

```
CROSS APPLY xi.[LoadedXML].nodes('tcpos-export/transactions/transaction') x3(payments)

CROSS APPLY x3.payments.nodes('payment[
    code/text() 
]') x4(payment)
```

and in select at the end:

**payment.value('(code/text())[1]','varchar(100)')**

but when i run the query it stays running and running, and got freezed. I dont know what else i can do.

Please give me some tips.

thank you

Comment: Is there always only one `Payment` node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- You can just select the values directly in your `select`

```sql
SELECT 
        trans.value('(shop/description/text())[1]','varchar(100)') tienda,
        trans.value('(payment/amount/text())[1]','numeric(18,2)') caja,
        -- etc....

FROM [dbo].[XmlImport] xi
-- etc....
```

- Alternatively, you can do another `CROSS APPLY nodes`. This is what you were trying to do, but it should be `x1.trans.nodes('payment')` because you want to break out each `Payment` node from `transaction`, not from the root XML.

> Note that the `VALUES` clause I added in [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004945/14868997) was needed only because we needed to refer multiple times to the same node.

```sql
SELECT 
        trans.value('(shop/description/text())[1]','varchar(100)') tienda,
        trans.value('(till/code/text())[1]','varchar(100)') caja,
        trans.value('(cashier/code/text())[1]','varchar(100)') cajero,
        trans.value('(beginning-timestamp/text())[1]','varchar(100)') fecha,
        trans.value('(trans-num/text())[1]','varchar(100)') transaccion,
        item.value('(code/text())[1]','varchar(100)') itemcode,
        item.value('(description/text())[1]','varchar(100)') description,
     
        item.value('(hash-code/text())[1]','int') hashcode
        payment.value('(code/text())[1]','int') paymentCode
FROM [dbo].[XmlImport] xi

CROSS APPLY xi.[LoadedXML].nodes('tcpos-export/transactions/transaction') x1(trans)

CROSS APPLY x1.trans.nodes('trans-item[
    hash-code/text() and
    not( unit-price[contains(text()[1], "-")] ) and
    not( taxable-amount[contains(text()[1], "-")] ) and
    not( delete-operator-id/text() )
]') x2(item)

CROSS APPLY x1.trans.nodes('payment') x3(payment)

ORDER BY hashcode;
```

Note that if there might be no `payment` node then you need `OUTER APPLY` not `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: and what you recommend? by selecting directly or creating a new node like you did? theres any diff between them in terms of flexibility?

Comment: Yes i did not understand that one from my previous post why you put a values clause and not use them directly? its because im using CASE statements?

Comment: If you select directly from `LoadedXML` then you will get *all* `payment` nodes, even ones from other `transaction` nodes, you need it to be correlated. As I said, the previous question needed to refer to those values `quantity` and `weight` multiple times, so they were places in a `CROSS  APPLY (VALUES`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818438/possible-to-store-value-of-one-select-column-and-use-it-for-the-next-one/65818648#65818648

Comment: also i saw instead of where clauses you use always  cross apply instead right? what about group by? can i user it like that last Order by?

Comment: It's usually faster to filter XML directly within XQuery. To use `GROUP BY` you need `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` because you would be referring to the same value twice. Again, you want each `payment` node *as it relates to its parent `transaction` node* you don't want *all* `payment` nodes from the whole XML against every single `transaction`. Try both and you'll see the difference.

Comment: And you right, i need to get all payment nodes from that .XML file as im using it to create one big invoice in my ERP system. I need to send all items, quantity, unitprice, taxes. Thats why i asked why not use select directly from Loaded XML

Comment: Sorry, but how i can filter directly from xquery? for example i need to GROUP by this value '(trans-num/text())[1]','varchar(100)') and sum all payment amount values (payment/amount/text() into one row group by trans-num and other fields